# jquery kill hover rules when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, click, hover

I have 2 jquery events.

```
$('#thebutton').click(
```

and.....

```
$('#thebutton').hover(
```

Obviously once you hover onto the button, the hover event activates. once you click the button i want that event to fire so i can manipulate the button, but also kill the mouseoff event so that changes are kept.

Or as i just about to submit, should the click event be inside the hover? if so you'd still need to kill the mouseoff im guessing....

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to "not execute" mouse leave if you click while hovering?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate the button"?

Answer (score 0):

Then you wouldn't use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), you would use [`mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

```
   $('#thebutton').mouseover(function(){
        // do your mouse over here
   });


   $('#thebutton').click(function(){
       // do your click code here
    });
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `$(this).hover(function(){ return false });`. I assume you are trying to `stopImmediatePropagation` but how does it even help, perhaps the same code inside mouseleave might do the trick, but I would use a simple boolean to check inside mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger the 'mouseleave' event when you click the button... assuming that you want the associated function executed:

```
$('#thebutton').click(function(){
   $(this).trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to stop executing `mouseleave` in hover if the button is clicked.

Probably you can use a simple boolean to check if it clicked or not..

```
var isClicked = false;
$('#thebutton').click(function () {
    isClicked = true;
    //Your code
});

$('#thebutton').hover(function () { //mouseenter
    isClicked = false;
    //Your code
}, function() { //mouseleave
    if (isClicked) return false;
    //Your code
});
```